# Cannot set ACL on ACL-enabled EXT4 partition

Tags: permissions, debian-squeeze, access-control-list, ext3, ext4

I am trying to enable xattrs and acls on a Debian machine. I've (re)mounted the partition in question with user_xattr and acl. (/dev/md3 is the partition in question)

```
root@fs01:/# mount | grep /dev/md
/dev/md0 on / type ext3 (rw,noatime,nodiratime,barrier=1,user_xattr,acl)
/dev/md3 on /DataVolume type ext4 (rw,noatime,nodiratime,acl,user_xattr)
```

And the ACL tools are installed.

```
root@fs01:/# dpkg-query -W -f='${Status} ${Version}\n' acl
install ok installed 2.2.49-4
root@fs01:/# dpkg-query -W -f='${Status} ${Version}\n' libacl1
install ok installed 2.2.49-4
```

Xattrs worked out of the box; ACLs didn't. Getfacl works without error:

```
root@fs01:/# getfacl /DataVolume/hi
# file: /DataVolume/hi
# owner: root
# group: root
user::rw-
group::rw-
other::rw-
```

because it is only returning the native *nix permissions; there aren't any ACLs because I can't set them:

```
root@fs01:/# setfacl -m u:root:rwx /DataVolume/hi
setfacl: /DataVolume/hi: Operation not supported
```

I'm assuming that it's disabled in the kernel, but I can't find any way to check it; kernel config file/source isn't provided for this particular build... (Packaged for an embedded system, unnecessary files were stripped out to minimize footprint) But if it was disabled in the kernel, I wouldn't be able to mount the partition with the acl flag, correct? Any help is appreciated!

(Originally posted on superuser.com - moved here after no interest.)

Comment: Your kernel config may be available in `/proc/config.gz`  if one isn't stored in `/boot`.

Comment: Unfortunately not; it boots from a uBoot image, so no config in `/boot`. There isn't one in `/proc` either, though I'm not entirely sure why. Likely the same reason...

Comment: I'm fairly certain you can mount the filesystem with the acl option even if the kernel lacks ACL support. I haven't checked, but I think the kernel will verify at mount time whether the options you specified are valid for the filesystem type (and "acl" is a valid option for ext4); this is orthogonal to the behaviour of setfacl, which will just return an error if the kernel support isn't there.